# Keras - Issues with tensors shape with TensorFlow backend

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning, classification, keras

I am trying to transform a TensorFlow script into Keras. I have a classification model which predicts the presence of digits and 4 digits. I have two different losses and two outputs: one for the presence and one for the digits.

This is my model :

```
def get_training_model2():
    inp, x = convolutional_layers2()
    x = Flatten()(x)
    x = Dense(2048)(x)
    x = Activation('relu')(x)
    y = Dense(1+5*len(DIGITS), activation='softmax')(x)
    out1 = Lambda(lambda a: a[:,:1])(y)
    out2 = Lambda(lambda a: a[:,1:])(y)
    model = Model(inp, [out1, out2])
    return model
```

This is my digit loss :

```
def digits_loss(y_true, y_pred):
    digits_loss = losses.sparse_categorical_crossentropy(K.reshape(y_true, [-1, len(DIGITS)]),
                                                         K.reshape(y_pred, [-1, len(DIGITS)]))
    digits_loss = np.sum(digits_loss)
    return digits_loss

# Target    
target = [y_train[:,:1],  y_train[:,1:]]
```

When I launch :

```
model = model_keras.get_training_model2()
opt = Adam(lr=learn_rate)
model.compile(loss=[presence_loss, digits_loss],
              optimizer=opt,
              metrics=['accuracy'])

model.fit(X_train, target, batch_size=50,
          epochs=50 ...)
```

I have this error :

```
File "train_keras.py", line 96, in digits_loss
    K.reshape(y_pred, [-1, len(DIGITS)]))
logits and labels must have the same first dimension, got logits shape [250,11] and labels shape [2750]
```

I don't understand why I have this error because I am reshaping both labels and logits in the same way. Moreover, I don't understand why the shape is [250,11] although it's should be [50, 11] (batch_size).
Thank you for any help.

Comment: Can you add more context? I don't understand where you call digits_loss. Also, your implementation of digits_loss calls np.sum which is not a tensorflow op and will fail.

Comment: Sorry for the lack of context. I have edited my post with the model compilation (with two losses). 
Is it really a problem that the loss is not a TensorFlow op while using Keras because the model compiling. My error is appearing during the training (`model.fit`).
Thanks

Comment: Can you print the tensor shapes before passing them to sparse_categorical_crossentropy? It doesn't make sense to me that you're getting these expressions.

Comment: Before sparse_categorial_cross_entropy:
y_true (?, ?)
y_pred (?, 55)
K.reshape(y_true, [-1, len(DIGITS)]) (?, 11)
K.reshape(y_pred, [-1, len(DIGITS)]) (?, 11)
Other shapes : 
X_train : (50, 64, 128, 1)
y_train for presence loss: (50, 1) 
y_train for digits loss: (50, 55)

Comment: Then I don't understand how you can have this error.

Comment: Yeah ... Me too, thanks anyway